# Excel Macro to give report title based on Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am very new to macro programming and currently creating a macro that splits a table into new worksheets dependent on a unique variable, then copies and pastes each worksheet into a single word document split by page breaks.

What I cannot work out how to do, is create a macro that gives each table on each page a title based on the value of a cell.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Run_All()
Call Organise_Table
Call Rename_Column
Call Isblank
Call Split_Table
Call SumColumn
Call ExceltoWord
Call Report_Title   
End Sub

Sub Organise_Table()
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Sub Rename_Column()
    Range("A1") = "Contribution Type"
    Range("B1") = "RefNo"
    Range("C1") = "Title"
    Range("D1") = "Initals"
    Range("E1") = "Surname"
    Range("F1") = "Balance Brought Forward"
    Range("G1") = "Annual Interest Added"
    Range("H1") = "Contributions Added"
    Range("I1") = "Total Fund Value"
End Sub

Sub Isblank()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    With Range("F1:I14")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Err.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Split_Table()

Dim lr As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim iCol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim Title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

vcol = 2
Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Title = "A1:I14"


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
titlerow = Ws.Range(Title).Cells(1).Row
iCol = Ws.Columns.Count
Ws.Cells(1, iCol) = "Unique"


For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
  If Ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ws.Cells(i, vcol), Ws.Columns(iCol), 0) = 0 Then
  Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Ws.Cells(i, vcol)
  End If
Next i
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Ws.Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
Ws.Columns(iCol).Clear
  For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    Ws.Range(Title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    Ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
  Next i
Ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Ws.Activate
End Sub

Sub SumColumn()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim nSheets As Integer

For nSheets = 1 To 3

With Worksheets(nSheets)

LastRow = 0

For iCol = 6 To 9
iRow = .Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
If iRow > LastRow Then LastRow = iRow
Next iCol

For iCol = 6 To 9
.Cells(LastRow + 1, iCol) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(LastRow, iCol)))
Next iCol


iCol = 1
.Cells(LastRow + 1, iCol).Value = ("Total")

End With

Next nSheets

End Sub


Sub ExceltoWord()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Wkbk1 As Workbook
Dim strdocname As String
Dim wdapp As Object
Dim wddoc As Object
Dim orng As Object
Dim wdAutoFitwindow As String



    Set Wkbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    strdocname = "\\VDC.COM\User\HomeDrives\GFSNRE\Desktop\Test19.Doc" 'Change this to whatever directory the report will be in

    'file name & folder path
    On Error Resume Next
    'error number 429
    Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Err.Clear
        'create new instance of word application
        Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    wdapp.Visible = True
    'define paths to file
    If Dir(strdocname) = "" Then
        'MsgBox "The file" & strdocname & vbCrLf & "was not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Path\Name.doc", _
         '       vbExclamation, "The document does not exist "
        'Exit Sub
        Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Add
    Else
        Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strdocname)
    End If
    For Each Ws In Wkbk1.Worksheets
        Ws.Range("A1:I14").Copy
        Set orng = wddoc.Range
        orng.collapse 0
        orng.Paste
        orng.End = wddoc.Range.End
        orng.collapse 0
        orng.insertbreak Type:=7
        Range("A1:I14").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        wddoc.AutofitBehavior wdAutoFitwindow
        Next Ws

lbl_Exit:
    Set orng = Nothing
    Set wddoc = Nothing
    Set wdapp = Nothing
    Set Wkbk1 = Nothing
    Set Ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub Report_Title()

   Dim Ws As Worksheet
   Dim MyText As String
   Dim MyRange As Object

   Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Range

   MyText = Ws.Range("E3").Value
   ' Selection Example:
   Selection.InsertBefore (MyText)
   ' Range Example: Inserts text at the beginning
   ' of the active document.
   MyRange.InsertBefore (MyText)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code (edit your question, button is just under the tags) that you have at the moment, even if it doesn't work! It'll be far easier for us to work with something!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, added it now. It's the last sub function at the bottom that requires work. For Example, I need the value of E2 to provide the title in a word document. It's a bit of a hack job sorry!

Comment: I'm not an expert of Word VBA, but as you work with both Excel and Word here, you'll need to specify in which application you are working, especially for `Selection` which should be `wdapp.Selection` or `xlapp.Selection` (and before, define xlapp with `Set xlapp = Application` as you work in excel)

Comment: Just a thought: add your table title in each sheet in excel itself on row 1 with merged and centered across column A-I. Then proceed to copy range A1:I15 to word.

Answer (score 0):

There is one error here :

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim MyText As String
Dim MyRange As Object

Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Range

MyText = Ws.Range("E3").Value '<==== WS is not properly defined yet
```

You are using Ws. to say in which worksheet you are working in, which is a good thing. But, as it is a procedure-level variable, it is not pointing anywhere useful. You probably need something like :

```
Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Range 
Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'assuming you want to read "E3" on the sheet "Sheet1" of the active workbook, that's the line to add
MyText = Ws.Range("E3").Value '<==== WS is now properly defined
```

If you go to debugging mode, you should have nothing in "MyText" in your version, and something in mine. The content of E3 in the sheet Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You should not turn off error handling for the entire code. If
   things aren't working VBA can't tell you why or where the problem
   is. While it's standar practise to use On Error Resume Next when
   using GetObject/CreateObject it's also standard practise to turn
   error handling back on AFTER the If...End If. You need to add the
   line: On Error GoTo 0 where you have no error handler code.

   2. Based on your sample code, write in the Title before pasting the table.

So something like this:

```
For Each Ws In Wkbk1.Worksheets
   Ws.Range("A1:I14").Copy
   Set orng = wddoc.Range
   orng.collapse 0
   orng.Text = Ws.Range([cell reference with title]) & vbCr
   orng.collapse 0
   orng.Paste
   orng.End = wddoc.Range.End
   orng.collapse 0
   orng.insertbreak Type:=7
   Range("A1:I14").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   wddoc.AutofitBehavior wdAutoFitwindow
Next Ws
```